# Change margin size in cover page

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to add a cover page which is already created in a PDF.

````
```{r echo=FALSE,out.width='8.27in',out.height='11.69in'}
knitr::include_graphics('CoverPage.pdf')
```
````

I want to change the margins of the *first page* only. Can you please help me with this?

The following was tried but it changes the margin of the whole document:

```
geometry: "left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are fine with some bare LaTeX in your RMD file, then this can be easily achieved using the [`geometry` package](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf). Just define a `newgeometry` before the cover is included and `restoregeometry` afterwards (reads almost like English …).

````
---
output:
  pdf_document
---
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
cat("\\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}")
knitr::include_graphics("CoverPage.pdf")
cat("\\restoregeometry")
```

\clearpage

Note the position of the page number. Restoring the margins was successful!
````

It is important to use the chunk option `results="asis"` and `cat()` to print raw LaTeX and to escape the backslashes with an additional backslash.

Comment: you just saved my life, thank you! Page numbering was messing with my margins, adding your code fixed the margins for the part of the document where it was not working!